# Access to Shiny app in another computer within the same network

Tags: r, windows, rstudio, shiny

I've created a Shiny app that runs perfectly when I run it in my computer (I have the "ui.R" and "server.R" files in a directory of my desktop).

But I want to other people in my workplace (also using R and RStudio) can also run it.

I copy the "ui.R" and "server.R" files to a directory in another computer, so anyone with the permissions can access this app.

The problem is that when I move this files to other computer's folder I can't run the app anymore. It gives me the error "No Shiny application exists at the path..."

I set the working directory to this new path where I put the files, so I don't know where the problem is. I have lecture and writing permissions to this folder.

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: How about create a new Shiny app on the other computer, and then overwrite the files with yours?

Comment: That's the easy solution and probably the one I'm going to apply. But I want to know if all the people could access from the same two files, instead of sending the archives to every person.

Comment: Here are a few ideas http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/deployment-local.html Ultimately, you can setup a Shiny Server in your office network to serve the app to everyone.

Comment: A great solution would be to create a Shiny Sever or work with shinyapps.io, but I don't think I can implement neather of those on my company.

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way would be keep server.R and ui.R in one script without copying to a specific area. 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)